# C++ function overloading, alternatives to enable_if?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, c++03

If I have a function, `insert`, within a templated class, and I overload it to take either a fill pattern:

```
void insert(const size_type N, const value_type &element);
```

or a range pattern:

```
template <class iterator_type>
void insert(const iterator_type begin, const iterator_type end)
```

When I specify the `value_type` of the class to be int, it results in the following call:

```
insert(500, 50);
```

being ambiguous, as it assumes `500` to be an `int` and therefore not a match for `size_type N`, and instead of calling the fill pattern function, calls the templated range function and fails.

This is a C++03-compatible library,- it can't use external libraries like boost, only builtin C++ code. The only workaround I've found that doesn't require C++11's `enable_if` would be creating additional overloads, replacing `size_type` with `int`, `long int`, `char` etc, and calling the fill function from them. Obviously this is problematic because you can have so many different types which match `500`. Any suggestions?

Comment: `enable_if` is perfectly implementable in C++03. Takes half a dozen lines of code.

Comment: Take a look at [std::vector's constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), which have among them exactly those overloads.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. [Unable to reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f930cf791890bace)

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper What, exactly, do you expect to "reproduce" with that?

Comment: @T.C. If there's some magical information that you're deriving from the question the rest of us can't see, feel free to share it.

Comment: Depending on `iterator_type`, a simple SFINAE can be defined which would separate between the 2 overloads. Otherwise, because the `template` overload is anyways generating the error, you may replace those erroneous method invocations with `insert(size_t(500), size_t(5))` and make a simple workaround.

Comment: Tagged function might be an alternative (or a simple renaming).

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper Fixed your "test".
3309b55c250a1147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Puppy's answer figured it out:

```
// Fill insert
void insert(const size_type N, const value_type &element);


// Enable_if template
template <bool condition, class T = void> 
struct enable_if_c
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <class T>
struct enable_if_c<false, T>
{};


// Range insert:
template <class iterator_type>
iterator insert (const typename enable_if_c<!std::numeric_limits<iterator_type>::is_integer, iterator_type>::type &first, const iterator_type &last);
```

numeric_limits is C++03-safe and works in all (tested) compilers including MSVC 2010. This checks to make sure the type supplied to range-insert is not an integer.

Comment: A note on the usage of `enable_if`/`enable_if_c`. If possible, you better always apply it to the return type (rather than to the parameter type). The problem is that if some template parameter type of your template function doesn't appear in the function parameter list *without being wrapped in* `enable_if` then that function will never be considered during overload resolution. In this case, there is no problem since `iterator_type` is used for the second parameter (`last`) as is. Try wrapping it in `enable_if_c` too, and you will see that the compilation will break.

Comment: Interesting. What causes this behaviour (ie. what is the logic behind it)? In this case it's not possible to wrap the return type, as it can't be whatever external iterator (vector<>::iterator, deque<>::iterator) is thrown at it, but the function Must handle those iterators.

Comment: It should be possible. Did you try `template <class iterator_type> typename enable_if_c<!std::numeric_limits<iterator_type>::is_integer, iterator>::type insert (const iterator_type &first, const iterator_type &last);`?

Comment: You don't understand. This is for a templated class. Insert should never, Ever return the iterator type supplied to the function. It should only Ever return the class's own iterator ie. 'iterator'. The same applies for any standard library container ie. vector, deque, etc. They are all designed to allow for range insert from other types of containers with the same value_type. Returning the same iterator type that is supplied is not useful.

Comment: The declaration of `insert()` in my previous comment does exactly that. The type `enable_if_c<condition, iterator>::type` stands for `iterator` when `condition == true` (and is an error when `condition == false`).

Answer (score 3):

Take advantage of SFINAE:

```
void insert(const size_type N, const value_type &element);

template <class iterator_type>
void insert(iterator_type begin, iterator_type end, char (*)[sizeof(*begin)] = NULL);
```

The extra dummy argument in the range version of `insert` will be optimized out by the compiler. Its only role is to eliminate the template function from overloading resolution for types that cannot be used with a dereference operator.

Clarification of the trick:

`char (*)[sizeof(*begin)]` stands for a pointer to an array of chars whose size is equal to `sizeof(*begin)`. If the variable `begin` is not dereferenceable then this would be an error. However, in the context of considering a function template during function overload resolution, such an error doesn't stop compilation, but simply discards the template (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error - SFINAE).

Comment: This is an interesting solution. It will be also good, if you explain what exactly `char (*)[sizeof(*begin)]` does for the novice visitors. Upvote from me.

Comment: This actually requires expression SFINAE, which is (mostly) C++11.

Comment: @T.C. It compiles with `gcc 4.4.7` (which doesn't even recognize the `--std=c++03` option), with `gcc 5.3 --std=c++03`, and with `clang 3.0 & 3.7` (both with `--std=c++03`)

Comment: Yes, GCC 4.4 is the first release to support that (https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11, search for "Solving the SFINAE problem for expressions"), backported to their C++98/03 mode.

Comment: A very good solution, but unfortunately incompatible with a vast swath of compilers. Thank you for it though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact compilers you support, you may find enable_if as a builtin anyway- it's present in TR1.

However, the implementation of enable_if is trivial. You could simply copy it from Boost as well. In fact, it's so short I'm going to post it in this answer.

```
namespace boost
{

  template <bool B, class T = void>
  struct enable_if_c {
    typedef T type;
  };

  template <class T>
  struct enable_if_c<false, T> {};

  template <class Cond, class T = void> 
  struct enable_if : public enable_if_c<Cond::value, T> {};

  template <bool B, class T>
  struct lazy_enable_if_c {
    typedef typename T::type type;
  };

  template <class T>
  struct lazy_enable_if_c<false, T> {};

  template <class Cond, class T> 
  struct lazy_enable_if : public lazy_enable_if_c<Cond::value, T> {};


  template <bool B, class T = void>
  struct disable_if_c {
    typedef T type;
  };

  template <class T>
  struct disable_if_c<true, T> {};

  template <class Cond, class T = void> 
  struct disable_if : public disable_if_c<Cond::value, T> {};

  template <bool B, class T>
  struct lazy_disable_if_c {
    typedef typename T::type type;
  };

  template <class T>
  struct lazy_disable_if_c<true, T> {};

  template <class Cond, class T> 
  struct lazy_disable_if : public lazy_disable_if_c<Cond::value, T> {};

} // namespace boost
```

Comment: `enable_if` is not enough, some `type_traits` are required too.

Comment: Found the above could be reduced to: "  template <bool B, class T>
  struct enable_if_c {
    typedef T type;
  };
" for the tests required in this case, but all the tests for iterators I've seen require c++11 features.